# Firebase realtime database Creating a way to mimic multi tenant design

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

We have built an analytics apps  which will capture data for our customers. The idea is to create a node in firebase db per customer and have all their captured data in that node.

This idea works fine for the realtime DB as we can prepend customer name in all firebase db operations from client side.

The problem is on firebase functions. For example one of the function look like:

```
exports.on_new_message = functions.database.ref(orgName + "/messages/{id}")
    .onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {
        console.log("start of on_new_message ")   
        const message = snapshot.val();
 })
```

in this case orgName is hard coded at this moment. And we are not sure how to generalize it in a way that the root node does not need to be specified.  For a quick ref the data may look like

```
 orgA
   --messages
      ---
      ---
   --stats
     --
     --
 orgB
    --messages
      ---
      ---
   --stats
     --
     --
```

If above architecture sounds down right dumb then please advise the right way

Comment: Could you give more detail (and maybe a concrete example) on the path you want to trigger your Cloud Function?

Comment: so the path would be orgA/messages for  customer orgA and orgB/messages for customer orgB. Does this help ?

Comment: Yes, it is more clear, thanks. And what is your problem?

Comment: I mean why don't you just do `functions.database.ref("{orgId}/messages/{id}")` ?

Comment: well i thought this may work but was not sure and we dont have enough development done to test it.

Comment: This will work. I'll write an answer with more details.

Comment: It's not advisable to create multitenant apps with a single Firebase project, as you will likely encounter many problems with this in the future.  It's recommended to create different Firebase projects for each customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have **several** wildcards in the path, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database#.ref

So you could do

```
exports.on_new_message = functions.database.ref("{orgName}/messages/{id}")
    .onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {
        console.log("start of on_new_message ");   
        const message = snapshot.val();

        const orgName = context.params.orgName;
        const messageId = context.params.id;

        //....     

 })
```

Comment: so how do i define index on these dynamic nodes?

Comment: @MoblizeIT I would suggest that you ask a new SO question for that.